# Python script executing to SQL databse: COUNT field incorrect.. ERROR

Tags: python, sql

I have some python script that executes to a SQL server.  Error log says that something is happening in this, sqlInsrt() function.  The error is:

```
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error')
```

Can anyone explain what is possibly going wrong here?  I've had SQL errors before that are perhaps similar to this ("# of parameters expected, # of parameters given) for example

The function is below

```
def sqlInsrt(headers, values):
        #create string input of mylisth
        strheaders = ','.join(str(i) for i in headers)

        #create string input of %s corresponding to number of entries in mylisth
        placestr = ','.join(str(i) for i in ['?' for i in headers])

        #Setup and execute SQL query 
        replacestr = ', '.join(['{}=?'.format(h) for h in headers])
        insert = ("INSERT INTO capacitors ({strheaders}) VALUES ({placestr}) \
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {replacestr}").format(
                    strheaders=strheaders, placestr=placestr, replacestr=replacestr)
        cursor.execute(insert, values*2)
        cnx.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Does strheaders and placestr have same length?
It looks like you're requiring wrong column.

Comment: Ah, I see now, they are different lengths.  Yuck, I had just changed a little bit of code above this function that altered their list lengths and it slipped my mind that I would have to accommodate for that in the SQL statement.  Thanks for the quick spot!